# WebViewClient::onReceivedSslError is not called

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I have attached my WebViewClient implementation to my WebView.

```
appView.setWebViewClient(new AppViewClient());
```

My `onReceivedSslError` and `onReceivedError` implementations are called with all expected errors except for `Mixed Content` error.

My implementation for both methods:

`Log.i(TAG, "Error Cought");`

As I said, they are called on various errors except the `Mixed Content` error. My request is blocked without calling either of these methods.

Comment: The problem might be from unstated cause. I believe some elaborations will  help, together with showing the code...

Comment: @Xenolion the Mixed Content error is known and can be easily reproduced. I am not looking for answer to solve this error. The solution is known. But I am looking for a way catch the error in order to perform some logic instead.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that. You should give some more explanation and show some code. People can not answer the question correctly when there is only few details and no code!

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which API version are you using?
`MIX CONTENT` was allowed, by default, before 21.

You can try adding this setting in web view:

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW);
```

For API level below 21 :

```
try {
    Method m = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setMixedContentMode", int.class);
    if ( m != null ) {

     m.invoke(webView.getSettings(), 1); //MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW

    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Good to know that you already know about MixedContentMode :) I can
    suggest 2 things to try.

1. Use console message to identify this error. You can do a string match to check the MIX CONTENT error.

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
    Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line "
                         + lineNumber + " of "
                         + sourceID);
  }
});
```

2. Intercept request and check the url. Check the WebActivity implementation in [source code](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/src/com/android/managedprovisioning/preprovisioning/WebActivity.java).

   ```
   mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               @Override
               public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                       WebResourceRequest request) {
                   String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                   if (!URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(url)) {
                       Logger.loge("Secure connection required, but insecure URL requested "
                               + "explicitly, or as a part of the page.");
                       return createNewSecurityErrorResponse();
                   }
                   return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
               }
           });




   private WebResourceResponse createNewSecurityErrorResponse() {
           WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
           response.setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase(HTTP_FORBIDDEN, "Secure connection required");
           return response;
       }
   ```

Comment: I already know about `setMixedContentMode` method. I am not asking about how to allow mixed content. I am asking how to received mixed content error in a callback method such as: `onReceivedError `

Comment: From Chrome console I can see the mixed content error. However, `onReceivedHttpError` and `onReceivedSslError` are not called.

Comment: Can I change the URL from inside 'shouldInterceptRequest' then proceed with the request :) ?

Comment: This is not a ssl error neither http error.they will not called. See the third aaproach, how android itself handle this case.

Comment: Regarding changing url, It's worth giving a try. Please update if you can change the url. If this answer your original question, accept this.

Comment: I wonder why my answer has -1. It should be accepted as answer.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated. But it does not provide an answer to the question. I really wish it answers it. I am stuck.

Comment: I believe your original question was "how to get callback for MIX CONTENT?" which is answered..
I show you a example in android framework but if you still think it doesn't answer your question than well all the best 